# Related Scheduler Job not created-Firebase Scheduled Function

Tags: node.js, firebase, cron, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-scheduler

I have written a scheduled function in node.js using typescript that successfully deploys.The related pub/sub topic gets created automatically but somehow the related scheduler job does not.

This is even after getting these lines

```
i  scheduler: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
i  pubsub: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
+  scheduler: all necessary APIs are enabled
+  pubsub: all necessary APIs are enabled
+  functions: created scheduler job firebase-schedule-myFunction-us-central1
+  functions[myFunction(us-central1)]: Successful create operation.

+  Deploy complete!
```

I have cloned the sample at https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/delete-unused-accounts-cron which deploys and automatically creates both the related pub/sub topic and scheduler job.

What could i be missing?

Comment: If the Firebase CLI doesn't work the way you expect, contact Firebase support directly with a bug report.  There's not much Stack Overflow can do to help. https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Answer (score 2):

Try to change `.timeZone('utc')` (per the docs) to `.timeZone('Etc/UTC')` (also per the self-contradictory docs).

Comment: This solved my problem. It's ridiculous. The docs are contradictory ...

Answer (score 1):

It seems that when using the 'every 5 minutes' syntax, the deploy does not create the scheduler job.

Switching to the cron syntax solved the problem for me

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your cron syntax isn't correct. [There are some tools to validate the syntax](https://crontab.guru/)

Check your firebase-debug.log

At some point,it will invoke a POST request to:

```
>> HTTP REQUEST POST https://cloudscheduler.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/*project_name*/locations/*location*/jobs
```

This must be a 200 response.